# Events Handlers Subscription confusion

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

I rarely need to use events,  with the amount of different syntax's that are valid, it gets confusing when I revisit them sometimes.

I was wondering what the fundamental difference between these two invocations are?

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler<int> OnBar;
}

var foo = new Foo();

EventHandler<TDTO> handler1 = (object obj, int args) => { /*do work*/ }
EventHandler<TDTO> handler2 = (object obj, int args) => { /*do more work*/ }

foo.OnBar += handler1;
foo.OnBar += handler2;
```

Or invoking like this

```
var foo = new Foo();

EventHandler<TDTO> handler1 = (object obj, int args) => { /*do work*/ }
handler1 += (object obj, int args) => { /*do more work*/ }

foo.OnBar += handler1;
```

Is the only that you've seperated the references so that you can unsubscribe to them individually?

Or is there added value of using one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical difference between these two ways of subscription. Regular event (that is - event which does not provide custom `add` and `remove`) is just a wrapper around delegate, the same delegate as `handler1` (for example) in your question. So you are comparing this:

```
Action @event= null;
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("A");
Action b = () => Console.WriteLine("B");
@event += a;
@event += b;
```

With this:

```
Action @event = null;
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("A");
Action b = () => Console.WriteLine("B");
a += b;
@event += a;
@event();
```

And there is no difference: in both cases invocation list of delegate `@event` contains delegates `a` and `b`. You can even remove `b` from invocation list even though you never called `@event += b`.

That said, it's very unusual to pass delegate with multiple handlers to event. Also, if event DOES provide custom implementation for `add` and `remove` - it might not expect such delegate. For example, if you call `foo.OnBar += ...` two times - custom `add` will be invoked 2 times. But if you pass already combined delegate, you call it just once, so `add` will also be invoked once. So I'd suggest to not do that and always pass single delegate to event, not precombine them.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies everything